# Need HP recovery partition info

Tags: windows-7, mbr

I'm configuring a new HP Pavillion DV4 with a 320 GB disk. I made the recovery DVDs, then did a couple other things (including deleting the recovery partition), and finally decided to restore the system.

Unfortunately, the recovery process fails; the three DVDs are read (the recovery program says "Reformatting the Windows partition" and "Copying files required to restore the hard drive") but after it finishes reading the 3rd, and the progress bar reaches 100%, it fails with error 0xe0f00013 - Googling it didn't return anything at all.

I'm afraid this may be because I deleted the partitions. So, I'm kindly asking for one of the following, in order of preference, from a HP Pavillion DV4 with a 320 GB hard disk or a similar enough one :

1) A dump of the MBR

2) The type and size of all the partitions in a "new" system

so I can try to make a partition table resembling the original one.

BTW, I thought the recovery DVDs were supposed to work even if the entire disk was wiped - isn't that the case?

Thanks!

Comment: they should work regardless of the state of the hard drive; when I worked at a computer repair company and we got laptops back from HP, they'd often ship us blank hard drives to be replaced and we'd use the recovery disks we had to restore the system. Any idea what the error code is? do you have a plain XP/Vista/7 (whatever the operating system is) disk?

Comment: The error code is 0xe0f00013. The full error message is "Recovery Manager could not restore your computer using the factory image. Please contact HP support. Error code: 0xe0f00013" which isn't terribly helpful :(

I'll try with a completely blank MBR and see what happens...

Answer (score 1):

I've been in the same/similar situation as yourself (in my case, I wiped the drive but no recovery dvds).

Unless you want the HP software that comes bundled, you can just get any old copy of windows matching the version that came with your computer and re-install fresh using the CD Key that's stickied to your case.

Answer (score 1):

xe0f00013 error mostly occurs when you try to install another version of Windows that is you try to change the OS.. and if you wish to go back to pre-installed OS of notebook then you need to purchase recovery disc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you Run Diagnostics to verify the funcionality of the hard drive? If not then run diagnostics.  On most HP Notebooks you can tap [‘F2’ on startup to access the diagnostics](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&docname=c01443317).

- If the hard drive fails it will Have To Be Replaced
- If the diagnostics pass it is probably a problem with your Recovery Disks

A dump of the MBR is not going to help, [Recovery Disks](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c00810334&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&jumpid=reg_R1002_USEN) ARE supposed to work even if the entire disk is wiped, and they rebuild the factory partitioning. If the HDD is intact then the problem is most likely with the Recovery Disks that you created.  Did you use high quality recordable media? I have seen many problems with the created disks from poor quality media, or the data may have been corrupted.

Are you in warranty?  If so try contacting HP Tech Support. If the Hard Drive is bad HP should replace it for you, and if the problem is your disks you **MIGHT** be entitled to a set of replacement disks.